# How can I use jQuery to make a validation icon appear somewhats slowly, fading in

Tags: asp.net, jquery, fade

Here's what I have so far but thing aren't really working. (I dragged the jQuery.js file from the Solution Explorer to the  area of my html.

```
    <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="SignUpFormTest._Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            //fade in the context of whatever is inside the div tag.
            $('#name').fadeIn("slow");
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body bgcolor="#FFFFFF">

<p>
Note that this form doesn't actually do anything
except illustrate the Required Field Validator.
</p>

<form id="frmValidator" action="required.aspx" method="post" runat="server">

    Enter Your Name:
    <asp:TextBox id="txtName" runat="server" />
    <div id="name"><asp:RequiredFieldValidator id="valTxtName" ControlToValidate="txtName" ErrorMessage='<img src="../Images/no.png">' runat="server" /></div>

    <br />
    <asp:button id="btnSubmit" text="Submit" runat="server" />

</form>
<p>
Hint: Try submitting it before you enter something.
</p>
</body>


</html>
```

> When validating the icon just pops up.

No fade in or anything. Also, I know my current solution is hacky, so I'd really like someone to tell me what I should do instead of a creating a DIV tag just for the purpose of one animation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure the reference to JQuery is valid and use this code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#name').hide().fadeIn("slow");
});
```

If I'm not mistaken, since the div is already visible in your case, jQuery will not fade it in. The `hide()` method ensures that the div is initially not visible and then fades in slowly.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $(document).ready(function() { 
document.getElementById('valTxtName').onpropertychange = function(){
            $('#name').fadeIn("slow"); 
}

});
```

Comment: That still makes it just pop up.